# Баг кастом контрола

Tags: c#, winforms

код контрола:

```
public class MyGroupBox : GroupBox
    {
        private Color _borderColor = Color.Black;

        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get { return this._borderColor; }
            set { this._borderColor = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //get the text size in groupbox
            Size tSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Text, this.Font);

            Rectangle borderRect = e.ClipRectangle;
            borderRect.Y = (borderRect.Y + (tSize.Height / 2));
            borderRect.Height = (borderRect.Height - (tSize.Height / 2));
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, borderRect, this._borderColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);

            Rectangle textRect = e.ClipRectangle;
            textRect.X = (textRect.X + 6);
            textRect.Width = tSize.Width;
            textRect.Height = tSize.Height;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.BackColor), textRect);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), textRect);
        }
    }
```

Когда окно выходит за пределы экрана, то при возврате происходит следующее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте перед рисованием делать e.Graphics.Clear

Comment: не понимаю когда нужно ставить